# Dropdown navigation menu with only css, can someone help?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/chrome/index.htm

Hi,

I'm trying to make a dropdown menu with only css.

I don't want to use javascript.

Can anyone help me to make this ?

Comment: Aren't the instructions on that website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Here is not a free-code website. Just to give you an idea take a look at this:

You can use [CSS pseudo classe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/pseudo-classes) `:hover` to determine to show submenus or not.
HTML:

```
<ul class="mainmenu" >
    <li>Main Menu One
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li>Menu Item</li>
            <li>Menu Item</li>
            <li>Menu Item</li>
            <li>Menu Item</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Main Menu Two
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li>Menu Item</li>
            <li>Menu Item</li>
            <li>Menu Item</li>
            <li>Menu Item</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Main Menu Three
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li>Menu Item</li>
            <li>Menu Item</li>
            <li>Menu Item</li>
            <li>Menu Item</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.mainmenu li{float:left; border:1px solid black;}
.mainmenu li:hover .submenu{display:block;}
.submenu{display:none;}
.submenu li{float:none;}
```

Look at [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wBwAA/)